# Can Javascript onClick work with classes

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, onclick

I can't work out this Javascript for the life of me.
I need help with the following code, here is the snippet:

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="submit" class="clicktoshow" />

  <form class="hidden">
  </form>
</div>
```

I am going to be using an array in PHP to display multiple containers using the same code so I want to avoid id's.

Basically the form is hidden and I want it to show when submit is clicked, there will be alot of container divs, so I don't want the click to show ALL the forms, just the one aligned with the input / in its parent element.

Is this possible?

Any help please :|?

Comment: If you are new to JavaScript see this great resource as well. [**https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
document.getElementsByClassName('clicktoshow')[0].onclick = function(Event){
     var form = Event.target.parentNode.children[1]; //form object 
     form.style.display = "block"; // form node action
};
```

If the class `repeated` in code then you will need to iterate event code
Like

```
var cls = document.getElementsByClassName('clicktoshow');
for(var i in cls){
  cls[i].onclick = function(Event){ 
   var form = Event.target.parentNode.children[1]; //form object 
    form.style.display = "block"; // form node action
 };
```

}

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QcXtF/1/)

NOTE : The code will work in modern browsers.

Comment: Hey, could you please emphasis on //your code here? What do I do to get the form to work in the script? Thanks!

Comment: @user3405517 check updated code as well as **demo** link, hope the code will be helpful,

Comment: It worked! Thanks a bunch! If i could please bother you for one more question, is there a way I can make it disappear :|?

Answer (score 0):

****Yes try this****

```
var clickClass= document.getElementsByClassName('clicktoshow');

clickClass.onclick = function(){
  // your code here
}
```

**[more info](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_document.asp)**

**[more info link 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)**

Comment: When I put my code inside the function do I need to add anything? I'm sorry if i sounds blatantly noob, I am learning Javascript!

Comment: Yes more about info than go here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: var clickClass= Document.getElementsByClassName('clicktoshow');

clickClass.onclick = function(){
  <form>
Show Content
  </form>
}   It doesn't seem to run am i missing something :\

Comment: now go this link and read carefully all topic about javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this....

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('clicktoshow');

element.onclick = function(){
  var parent = element.parentNode;
  var form = parent.getElementByClassName('hidden');
}
```